# Jekyll serve error: private method `select' called for "paginate":String

Tags: ruby, jekyll, jekyll-paginator

When trying to preview my blog locally using `jekyll build` I get the following error:

```
Error:  private method `select' called for "paginate":String
```

I'm new to Ruby and haven't been able to find a way to track down the source of this error. I'm hosting the blog on Github and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you added to your `_config.yml` file like this:

```
gems: jekyll-paginate
```

So, you should change to:

```
gems: [jekyll-paginate]
```